# Can you 'stack' a div *above* a div set to display: table-cell?

Tags: html, css, z-index, css-tables

I'm trying to create a toggle where you tap on one side and the background slides over to make that side 'active'.

To accommodate variable widths, I'm setting up the two sides of a toggle using `display: table`. This works great. I then add a 3rd `div` to the mix to act as the 'active button' that will slide back and forth.

The problem is this 3rd div. It ends up being on top of the text when I need it under. I was hoping z-index could solve the issue, but doesn't. Is there a way to accomplish what I want here?

The HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tbl">
    <div class="tbl-cl">1</div>
    <div class="tbl-cl">2</div>
    <div class="bgnd"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.tbl {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.tbl-cl {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.bgnd {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,.8);
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

[Live Demo @jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vuvibanora/1/)

Comment: `z-index` only applies to positioned element.

Comment: @j08691 A non static position that is ;)

Comment: Check this out: http://jsbin.com/xoqabu/1/edit As @j08691 pointed it out, `z-index` is not applicable to elements having `position` of `static`.

Comment: It's worth noting that absolute positioning changes the computed value of `display` for the table-cells to `block` and also `relative` positioning has no effect on table-cells (the effect of that is *undefined* in the spec). Therefore, there's no way to get `z-index` to work on table-cells.

Comment: @j08691 ARRRGGGHHHH. I'm slapping my forehead hard. 'doh! Thanks for jogging my brain!

Comment: I'm not sure what protocol is here. Should I just delete this question given how stupid the mistake was on my part? :)

Comment: a negative z-index would do the job : http://jsbin.com/pitugecugu/1/edit?html,css,output and this extra div could be a pseudo element too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can realize the layout by keeping the `.bgnd` element as a sibling of the CSS table.

You can then shift the "slider" to the right by adjusting the left offset.

**Note:** You could keep the `.bgnd` element as a child of `.tbl`, and the CSS will have the same effect.

```css
.wrapper {
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.tbl {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.tbl-cl {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}
.bgnd {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  top: 0;
  left: 0%; /* set to 50% to slide to right */
  width: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tbl">
    <div class="tbl-cl">1</div>
    <div class="tbl-cl">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bgnd"></div>
</div>
```